# what is the best practice to use promise.all?

Tags: javascript, api, typescript, promise

i have to make two calls and get consolidated response so in below code Promise.all is not being invoked any idea what is implemented wrong and i wanted to know best practice or approach in below scenario to achieve both request response using Promise.all.

I am using tsoa format in below code with typescript.

main.ts

```
   @Post("getStoreDetails")
   public async getStoreDetail(@Body() request: express.Request): Promise < any > {
       const stackurl = "http://staclurl"
       const storeurl = "http://storeurl"



       if (request.body.lob === "Stack") {
           const stack: any = await axios.post(stackurl, req.body).then(
               function(res) {
                   if (res.data.Header.StatusCode !== '0000') {
                       throw res.data.Header;
                   }
                   const Stackresponse = res.data.Details;
                   return Stackresponse;
               });
       }
       if (request.body.lob === "Admin") {
           const store: any = await axios.post(storeurl, req.body).then(
               function(res) {
                   if (res.data.Header.StatusCode !== '0000') {
                       throw res.data.Header;
                   }
                   const StoreResponse = res.data.Details;
                   return StoreResponse;
               });
       }


       return Promise.all([stack, store]);


   }
```

Comment: Both of those conditions can't be true so don't see why you would consider Promise.all. One of those variables will be undefined. Then since you use `await` neither variable will return a  promise

Comment: With `const`, neither of the two variables are in scope

Answer (score 1):

Your stack and store are inside a if statement, making them out of scope for the outer function. You can use an array in the function scope to store the two promises you create in the if statement. Note that you would have to remove await to get them to actually return promises that Promise.all would be able to resolve

Comment: Kind of getting what you saying can you give me some code examples ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is two fold:

1. `Promise.all` is used while only one condition can be true
2. Using the `await` keyword not correctly

the first mistake is that request.body.lob can only hold one value. Your Promises are inside an if statement. Therefore only one of them is getting returned.

The second mistake is that you are not really returning the promise but the value of the resolved promise because of the `await` keyword.

You are returning the **value of the promise** inside your `stack` and `store` variables **not the promises** itself. Therefore Promise.all can do nothing for you because there are not pending promises stored there.

Solve this by storing the promise in the variables and do the conditionals in a different manner.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you need is one request and set url based on conditional

```
@Post("getStoreDetails")
public async getStoreDetail(@Body() request: express.Request): Promise < any > {

  const urls = {
    'Stack': "http://staclurl",
    'Admin': "http://storeurl"
  }

  const url = urls[request.body.lob];

  if (url) {
    return await axios.post(url, req.body).then(
      function(res) {
        if (res.data.Header.StatusCode !== '0000') {              
          throw res.data.Header;
        }    
        return res.data.Details;
      });
  }else{
    // what to return if no matching url??
  }

}
```

Comment: in future lob could also come as an array and we have to make both calls simultaneously

Comment: any idea if we have both lobs in the request how we can achieve that with promise.all ?